# How do I find the values of a and b from this cubic polynomial?

Tags: calculus

Given that $g(x)=ax^3+bx^2+3x-2$ and $g'(1)=11$, $g''(2)=50$ where $a$, $b$ are constants, find the values of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
g'(1)=3a+2b+3\\
g''(2)=12a+2b
$$